# How to remove dataloading.net malware from browsers

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, malware, web-browser

I have recently installed one software from internet and it installed MacKeeper malware in my system. So every time when I open any link in any of the browser one page pops up in different window with dataloading.com and disappears.

It was frustrating as it was loading for every action (even for page refresh) you do on browser

Answer (score 1):

I did the followings to remove the malware from the system

1. `rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mackeeper.MacKeeper.MacKeeperPrivilegedHelper.plist`
2. `rm -rf ~/Library/UpdateMac`

Also you can install Komros app from Appstore to see the list of infected files. Komros app showed the above files which were infected and to remove them you have to upgrade it.

I tried with [malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/antimalware/mac/) software too, though it showed all the infected files and removed them, but still it was there in the system.

Use **find** command to know the path of the infected files and remove them and no need to upgrade any malware softwares.

Comment: macOS != Linux.  You would use the *BSD* command `find`.  See `man find` for more info. (And technically, it isn't *Linux* find.  It's *GNU* `find`)

Answer (score 0):

There are Malwarebytes or DetectX to remove the MacKeeper malware. RESTART after the removal.